# python how get returned value from async function

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

**Python 3.9** How i get returned value from async function !

---

```
import asyncio


async def test(asd: bool):
    if asd is True:
        print("true")
        return True
    else:
        print("not true")
        return False

# simple function return
res = test(asd=0)    
print(f"{res=}, {type(res)=}")
```

Comment: `my_response = asyncio.run(test(asd))`

Answer (score 0):

Change `p.rint` to `print`. You send 0 `asd = 0` its false then test return false and print "not true".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).